# Predicting language interference between Danish and Norwegian

Tags: multiple-languages, interference, danish, germanic-languages, norwegian

I am presently learning Danish, but will soon move to Norway. The languages are very similar, to the level that I can read both without ever having studied Norwegian. Norwegian pronunciation is likely to be easier to me than Danish one.

**What kind of interference between the languages should I expect?**

I am specifically interested in studies on what kinds of interference from Danish I will likely face, and how it will affect my learning of Norwegian.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am a language learner rather than a native speaker of Danish and Norwegian, I can confidently put forward that **there shouldn't be too much interference** due to some evidences I have encountered.

An [online article](https://www.tripsavvy.com/similarities-of-the-scandinavian-languages-1626432) written by Terri Mapes supports my decision, stating they are the most similar amongst all Scandinavian languages, the differences are made through [the orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Norwegian_Bokm%C3%A5l_and_Standard_Danish) of words; being slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The links seem to discuss the similarity of the languages, however, rather than the possible interference between them.

Comment: I understand, this would require looking at different lexical cases and a determination of loan words in each grammatical system since _almost every fjord and every valley has its special dialect incomprehensible to others_ [Djupedal, R. (2015)](https://www.aasentunet.no/iaa/en/nynorsk/The+Linguistic+Situation+in+Norway.d25-SxdLYXY.ips). I can add as well that Danish used to be the standard written language of Norway and this is referred historically as [The Norwegian language conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_language_conflict) for contributing much interference.